# Please help me interprete the results of my threeway interaction regression

Tags: interaction, interpretation, stata

Currently I examine if firm characteristics have an effect on firm communication. ESG, LARGE and CONTROVERSY are all indicator variables, set to zero or one.

1. I have big troubles interpreting my results.

My Stata regression equation is this:

```
reghdfe QUALITY x1 x2 x3 x4 ESG##CONTROVERSY##LARGE, absorb(FIRM Year) cluster(FIRM)
```

The model yields:

```
HDFE Linear regression                            Number of obs   =        802
Absorbing 2 HDFE groups                           F(  11,    214) =      20.02
Statistics robust to heteroskedasticity           Prob > F        =     0.0000
                                                  R-squared       =     0.6332
                                                  Adj R-squared   =     0.4855
                                                  Within R-sq.    =     0.0211
Number of clusters (FIRM)    =        215         Root MSE        =     0.0140

                                          (Std. err. adjusted for 215 clusters in FIRM)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                      |               Robust
              QUALITY | Coefficient  std. err.      t    P>|t|     [95% conf. interval]
----------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
                   x1 |  -.0000446   .0038578    -0.01   0.991    -.0076488    .0075597
                   x2 |   .0001482    .000103     1.44   0.152    -.0000548    .0003512
                   x3 |  -.0000391   .0000564    -0.69   0.489    -.0001502     .000072
                   x4 |   .0000958   .0000768     1.25   0.214    -.0000556    .0002472
                1.ESG |  -.0008591   .0023138    -0.37   0.711    -.0054198    .0037016
        1.CONTROVERSY |   .0190566   .0032089     5.94   0.000     .0127316    .0253816
                      |
      ESG#CONTROVERSY |
                 1 1  |  -.0175036   .0033864    -5.17   0.000    -.0241786   -.0108286
                      |
              1.LARGE |  -.0030138   .0044536    -0.68   0.499    -.0117923    .0057648
                      |
            ESG#LARGE |
                 1 1  |   .0067041   .0044098     1.52   0.130     -.001988    .0153963
                      |
    CONTROVERSY#LARGE |
                 1 1  |  -.0185935    .005275    -3.52   0.001    -.0289912   -.0081958
                      |
ESG#CONTROVERSY#LARGE |
               1 1 1  |   .0137926    .006862     2.01   0.046     .0002669    .0273183
                      |
                _cons |   .0666133   .0128766     5.17   0.000      .041232    .0919946
```

**Question 1:**
Based on this model output it seems that b#c,c#a and b#c#a are significant.
Is this line of thought correct:

In comparison to firms that are b=0 and c=0, firms with b=1 and c=1 combined provide 0.0175 lower quality disclosure, compared to what? Compared to firms with b=0 and c=0 average level of quality?

Afterwards I split the sample for a and found that the significant effects only persisted for a=0

Comment: There are good questions here, but too many.  It's likely an answer to the first question will resolve most or all of the remaining ones.  Could you shorten and focus this post?  BTW, most of this behavior is general, having nothing special to do with interactions.  Search our site for threads about [changes of significance in regression](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=regression%20significant%20not%20score%3a10).

Comment: Please excuse me for the various threads. I shortened the question. I hope it suffices now.

Answer (score 1):

With a 3-way interaction, each coefficient at a lower level for those predictors represents the situation where the other interacting predictors are at their reference levels. So the `ESG#CONTROVERSY` interaction coefficient of $-0.0175$ is only for the situation where `LARGE=0`. The values of non-interacting predictors (x1 through x4 here) won't matter in interpreting such coefficients.

The `ESG#CONTROVERSY#LARGE` interaction coefficient of $0.0138$ is the *difference* from that value when `LARGE=1`. The sum of those two coefficients is very close to 0, $-0.0037$, consistent with your subset analysis.

It might help to think this through by starting from the intercept and working your way up the hierarchy of coefficients. The intercept (`_const` here) is the estimate when *all* predictors are at reference levels (0 for numeric predictors). Each higher level of a coefficient is a *difference from* a lower level when the indicated predictor(s) change while the other predictors are held at reference levels. For any particular predictor or combination, however, it doesn't matter what values other predictors have that don't interact with it.

Comment: Dear EdM, thank you very much for this clarification. Especially the "up-working" helps a lot! Is it then right to say that I can not use this output to explain the "normal" effects of these variables? I should run a regression first without interaction terms. This shows in my case none of this variables is significant. How can I then show that the interaction is significant? I oriented at this: https://stats.oarc.ucla.edu/stata/faq/how-can-i-understand-a-three-way-interaction-in-anova-stata-12/ and it shows that my regression F statistics are not significant for either effect.

Comment: @Limps unless your model is overfit you should _not_ run regression without interaction terms. If a predictor is in an interaction, it has no single "'normal' effect": it's "effect" _depends on_ the values of its interacting variables. The apparent lack of significance in the model without interactions comes from the [omitted-variable bias](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Omitted-variable_bias) of removing important interactions. Start with the full model, use analysis of variance to evaluate the overall significance of each predictor, and examine estimates for particular predictor combinations.

Comment: can you please explain what you mean by overfit? I at least ran some RESET test that the specification is okay, but that does not shield me from OVB, right? Could you please elaborate how I perform analysis of variance for each predictor in stata? I followed the link above and got some computation: https://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/1695945-please-help-me-interpretate-the-interaction-effects-of-my-model-or-why-are-three-way-interactions-significant-but-two-way-are-not?p=1696368#post1696368 My final conclusion (see above 3.5) is that only Controversy

Comment: Is significant, and only if the other effects are zero.

Comment: @Limps overfitting happens when you try to estimate too many coefficients from too few observations, typically fewer than 15 observations per coefficient in this type of model. That doesn't seem to be a problem here but you should learn about that, for example in Chapter 4 of Harrell's [Regression Modeling Strategies](https://hbiostat.org/rmsc/). The Stata `anova` function used at the top of the page you linked is the type of test you need for evaluating overall significance of individual predictors and interactions, but I don't use Stata and don't know how to use that for this type of model.

Comment: I ran it, and found that none of my variables is signiciant. how is this possible?

Comment: @Limps it's hard to say what's going on without seeing the `anova` results. I suspect that your `anova` treated all of the 215 `FIRM` values as fixed effects, which uses up a lot of degrees of freedom and makes if difficult to find true differences. You need some type of analysis of variance on the `reghdfe` model. With the cluster treatment of `FIRM` by  `reghdfe`, that would need to be a set of tests on the coefficients based on the variance-covariance matrix of the estimates, as the independence assumption of other tests doesn't hold.